# No property EntityGraphType found for type Address

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I running a project, an error happens:

```
3:59:58.377 ERROR 3344 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addressController' defined in file [C:\IdeaProjects\finalTaskMonitoring\web\target\classes\com\example\controller\controllers\AddressController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addressService' defined in file [C:\IdeaProjects\finalTaskMonitoring\core\target\classes\com\example\service\AddressService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IAddressDao' defined in com.example.api.dao.IAddressDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Runner: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.api.dao.IDao.findAll(com.example.utils.enums.EntityGraphType,com.example.utils.pagination_settings.PaginationSettings) throws com.example.api.exceptions.dao.DataAccessException! No property findAll found for type Address!
```

I have 2 models: core (sevices, entities, utils) and web (controlles, api, mapper)
pom(core)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>finalTaskMonitoring</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

pom(web)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>finalTaskMonitoring</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>web</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>

        </dependency>
    </depen
```

dencies>

pom(general)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>finalTaskMonitoring</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>web</module>

    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>final_war</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>14</source>
                        <target>14</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.19</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Runner class

```
    @SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.example.api.dao" })
@AutoConfigurationPackage
@EnableSwagger2
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.example.model.dto.entities" })
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Runner.class, args);
    }
}
```

Adress controller:

```
    package com.example.controller.controllers;

import com.example.api.exceptions.service.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.example.api.exceptions.service.InternalServiceException;
import com.example.api.service.IAddressService;
import com.example.model.dto.simple.CollectionDto;
import com.example.model.dto.simple.MessageDto;
import com.example.model.dto.change.AddressChangeDto;
import com.example.model.dto.linked.AddressLinkedDto;
import com.example.model.dto.simple.AddressDto;
import com.example.model.validation_modes.CreateMode;
import com.example.model.validation_modes.UpdateMode;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/addresses")
public class AddressController {

    private final static String CREATE_IS_SUCCESS = "Address created successfully!";
    private final static String UPDATE_IS_SUCCESS = "Address updated successfully!";
    private final static String DELETE_IS_SUCCESS = "Address removed successfully!";
    private final IAddressService addressService;

    public AddressController(IAddressService addressService) {
        this.addressService = addressService;
    }
/// code


IAddressDao: 

    package com.example.api.dao;

import com.example.model.dto.linked.AddressLinkedDto;
import com.example.model.entities.Address;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface IAddressDao extends IDao<Address, Long> {


    void delete(AddressLinkedDto addressDelete);
}
```

IDao:

```
import com.example.api.exceptions.dao.DataAccessException;

import com.example.utils.enums.EntityGraphType;
import com.example.utils.pagination_settings.PaginationSettings;
import com.example.utils.singular_attribute_filter_settings.SingularAttributeFilterSettings;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface IDao<T, Id> extends CrudRepository<T, Integer> {
//    T save(T entity) throws DataAccessException;
//
//    void delete(Long id) throws DataAccessException;

    T update(T entity) throws DataAccessException;

    T findById(EntityGraphType graphType, Id id) throws DataAccessException;

    T findByAttribute(EntityGraphType graphType, PaginationSettings paginationSettings,
                      SingularAttributeFilterSettings singularAttributeFilterSettings) throws DataAccessException;

    List<T> findAll(EntityGraphType graphType, PaginationSettings paginationSettings) throws DataAccessException;

    List<T> findAllWithFilterSettings(EntityGraphType graphType, PaginationSettings paginationSettings, SingularAttributeFilterSettings singularAttributeFilterSettings) throws DataAccessException;

    Long getCount() throws DataAccessException;

    Long getCountByFilterSettings(SingularAttributeFilterSettings filterSettings) throws DataAccessException;

}
```

As I undanstand, It's happen because, Address have not EntityGraphType, PaginationSettings,SingularAttributeFilterSettings. How to solve this issue&

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The problem isn't with scanning but with creating your `IAddressDao`. The `findAll` method that it has inherited from `IDao` is causing a failure that's described as "No property findAll found for type Address!". Can you share the code for `IDao`?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Ok, added IDao